# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise (Update 3) Does not Apply Web Forms code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, webforms

2 days ago the Visual Studio worked perfect, but after the update I just can't work with it. The problem is that the Visual Studio does not apply my code in ASP.NET Web Forms, I see every time what I did one or two step back.

I tried to re-build the solution and it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What error do you get when rebuilding? Have you tried starting it as administrator?

Comment: When I running my website I didn't see something change. On the View Source in the google chrome I saw that my css file didn't changed, which mean That the Visual Studio doesn't apply my code on IIS. I tried to repair but not success.

Comment: So you made changes to a css file?

Comment: Yes I did make a changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be that you need to cache-bust your css file.
You can do this by adding a version number to your include (or using a variety of other methods: see https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/ )

Let's have a look at manually providing a version number:
You need to provide/change a version number on your css file that you modified like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=2">
```

Notice the ?v=2 part.
Your browser will interpret that there's a new version of your css file and will fetch the new version.

(Keep in mind you'll have to do the same for javascript files.)

Hope this helps.